# Minimize n functions

Tags: python, minimize

I have two functions whose distance (`y_1-y_2`) I need to minimize in order to obtain the best factor between the two (`dfactor`), so I can plot them together and fit them as best as posible. The difference with the examples from documentation is that, in this case, I have `n` points where I can compute the diference and thus I have `n`functions to minimize. With `scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar` I use the following syntax:

```
def chi(dfactor):
    for i in range(0, n):
        return abs(dfactor*y_1[i] - y_2[i])

res = minimize_scalar(chi)
print res.x
```

Now `res.x` is not the factor that best fits the two plots. I would expect to get an array of n elements, very similar between them where I can obtain a single `dfactor`that I need. But I am not sure `minimize_scalar` works like this.

Check the [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2uxa.png), where I compute the difference between the red dots and the corresponding point in the blue plot (represented here as lines as it is a spectrum) to overplot them as nicely as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have several return statements in a single function, only the first one will get called. Instead, you need to return some aggregate of the errors, such as the root means quared error:

```
# Convert to numpy arrays
y_1 = np.asarray(y_1)
y_2 = np.asarray(y_2)

def chi(dfactor):
    residual = dfactor * y_1 - y_2
    return np.mean(residual ** 2)

res = minimize_scalar(chi)
print res.x
```

Comment: So I should call the function in a loop _outside_ the function. Then I would need something like `chi(y1, y2, dfactor)`, but in that case how do I use `minimize_scalar` function?

Comment: No, as long as you want to find a single `dfactor`, my code should basically work *as is* for you.

Comment: I get a `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`, since `y_1`and `y_2` are lists of n elements.

Comment: I assumed y_1, y_2 were numpy arrays, I'll edit that.